# How to export a module from an linked JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

In my project if I load the main.js file the following works:

```
modules.exports = { property: value }
```

But if I load in a web page and it links to a script like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Then when I get an error,

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `module.exports` syntax is a feature of CommonJS modules, which is a module system used in Node.js but not supported in web browsers natively.

To use ES6 modules, you'll need to use a type="module" attribute on your script tag like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: This assumes that `main.js` is an ESM module.  The OP may actually be using nodejs CommonJS syntax in a client-side Javascript file which will not work, no matter what you do to the `<script>` tag.  `main.js` would need to be fixed so that it will work in a browser.